# list-style-type does not work for dangerouslySetInnerHTML in reactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Why is it so difficult to style list (ordered or unordered) in reactJS.
Reference case below, a user selects a file to load. These files are stored in html format in a special folder outside src folder.
Note that react components method cannot replace these html files. The main challenge is how to dynamically select and import user choice to main App.js
Now className and curly brackets do not work in html files. They create errors.
Hence I ended up using inline style for elements in these html files.
The inline style works for all the html elements. However for ol, ul and li, the list-style and list-style-type do not work. Even the default will not work.
One alternative I have is to use `<div><p><span></p></div>` to replace `<ol><li></li></ol>` This works fine but I will still prefer list method
Below the code and sample of the html file.
Any solution to this

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styles from './File.module.css';
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
import $ from 'jquery';

const SelectedFile = (props) => {
    const [file, setFile] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        try {
            $.post('php/get_selected_file.php', () => {
            }).done((data) => {                
                setFile(data);
            }).fail((xhr) => {
                alert(`An error ${xhr.statusText} has occurred. Please try later`);
            });
        } catch (error) {
              alert(`An error ${error} has occurred. Please try later`);
        };
    });

    const sanitizedFile = () => ({__html: DOMPurify.sanitize(file)});
    
    return (
        <div id='test_document' className={styles.classes} 
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={sanitizedFile()}
        />
    )
}

export default SelectedFile;
```

Below the html file

```
<div style="margin: 0.5rem 0; background-color: #ffe5e5; border: 1px solid #e31844; border-radius: 8px; padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem; ">
    <p>A</p>
    <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
        <li>Moon concept</li>
        <li>Sun concept</li>
        <li>
            <ol style="list-style-type: decimal;">
                <li>Radiation</li>
                <li>Earth energy balance</li>
                <li>Environmental impact</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: I created this demo with the code you provided. https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-pond-xpj5pz?file=/src/App.js - could you please clarify what is not working and what your expectation is?

Comment: Yes. it works. Thanks for your pointer. It made me saw my error. The code I posted is part of a bigger code. In it, I imported a module.css file which contains some ol, ul and li classes. I think react just ignored these classes and would not implement the inline styles in the html file.. Upon removing these classes of ol, ul and li from the css file, I got my expectations.